# Xcode 7.3 Upload to iTunesConnect (TestFlight build) failed

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

Previously we submitted an app using Xcode 7.3 but now it always fail with "iTunes store operation failed" error with Xcode 7.3 for the past 10 days.[image]

we made a build with Xcode 7.3 and uploaded by using Application loader 3.0 got "Missing Beta entitlement" and the build was not available for testing.
[image]

Comment: how do you upload it ? Did you try uploading using Application Loader ?

Comment: If we use application loader. In test flight build shows "Missing entitlement". Build cannot available for testing.

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of errors from both organizer and Application loader ?

Comment: I think you are using adhoc profile instead of distibution profile.

Comment: Yes we using ad hoc profile please wait for screenshot

Comment: Use distribution certificate and try to upload it. You can still have it in beta stage and add internal testers etc. ,

Answer (score 0):

```
 Please change the build Version then try to upload it. Make sure before building or archiving clean the project.
```

**First Thing**

```
  Here are the basic steps to upload the app form Application loader:

   1.Archive
   2.Export
   3.Xcode menu --> Xcode --> Open Developer Tool --> Application Loader
   4.Double click "Deliver Your App" and choose the file exported in step #2
   5.click next and follow the instructions until the end
```

**Second Thing**

```
   1.Set team in target-> General-> Team
   2.Check and set appropriate provisioning profile in targets/project build settings.
   3.Try with Xcode to upload build if find same issue. Or
   4.Try with application loader it will work.
```

If it is still not working then just upload the ipa with Application Loader 2.9.1.

Download Application Loader 2.9.1 or here

Comment: we tried many times but we cannot upload with Xcode 7.3. but with Xcode 8  it uploaded succesfully. (For our app some UI changes with Xcode 8)

Comment: "iTunes store operation failed". Cannot get any detailed information.

Comment: Ok, Thanks.. we will try

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem too, it seems that Xcode 7 build can only be sent by using the application loader of Xcode 8.
My suggestion is to build your app using xcode 7 export it as App Store build and upload using application loader but of Xcode 8. 
The application loader is inside Xcode menu->Open Developer Tool

Comment: Thanks, we also uploaded the build as you suggested. But we are facing "api-environment" key is missing error.

Answer (score 0):

It Will occur due to following reasons

```
1. I think you are using development or distribution certificates instead of app store certificates
2. Check once in your project folder target->capabilities->associated domains must be off before  submitting app to app store
3. Did you add application new version in iTunes store
```

Comment: 1. We using Adhoc distribution profile. 2.Associated domains is in Off state 3.No, we already had previous version, we tried to upload new version.

Comment: You  should have to create a new version for existing application

Comment: Yes, we incremented the version number. We are not submit the app to store. we try to update a TestFlight version for testing.

Comment: For new Version you have to create a version number in your i tunes account

Comment: We are not submit the app to store. we try to update a TestFlight version for testing.